# spring-ws deprecated DefaultHttpClient

Tags: apache-httpclient-4.x, spring-ws

I found that HttpComponentsMessageSender default constructor in spring-ws-core 3.4.0.RELEASE, which depends on httpclient 4.5.6, is instantiating a DefaultHttpClient() which is deprecated. However, when i tried to set a custom Httpclient with:

```
HttpComponentsMessageSender httpComponentsMessageSender = new HttpComponentsMessageSender(HttpClientBuilder.create().build());
```

httpComponentsMessageSender.setReadTimeout(1000l);

i got:

```
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: null
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.getParams(InternalHttpClient.java:211) ~[httpclient-4.5.6.jar:4.5.6]
    at org.springframework.ws.transport.http.HttpComponentsMessageSender.setReadTimeout(HttpComponentsMessageSender.java:149) ~[spring-ws-core-3.0.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
```

Is that correct that spring uses a deprecated class by default?
How should i set my custom HttpClient instance?
it seems that if i set my own HttpClient i cannot configure it through HttpCompoemntsMessageSender.

thanks,

Comment: What was the solution to this problem? Having the same issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not sure if you was able to resolve this but here is the solution to the following issue:

```
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: null
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.getParams(InternalHttpClient.java:211) ~[httpclient-4.5.6.jar:4.5.6]
    at org.springframework.ws.transport.http.HttpComponentsMessageSender.setReadTimeout(HttpComponentsMessageSender.java:149) ~[spring-ws-core-3.0.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
```

Note the **HttpComponentsMessageSender.setReadTimeout()** configures the underlying HttpClient's readTimeout by configuring the HttpClient Params.

As you provided above you can use the **HttpClientBuilder** to do this:

```
HttpComponentsMessageSender httpComponentsMessageSender = new HttpComponentsMessageSender(HttpClientBuilder.create().build());
```

The solution is to set the **"DefaultRequestConfig"** on the **HttpClientBuilder**

```
HttpClientBuilder.create()
                .setDefaultRequestConfig(requestConfig)
                .build();
```

As shown below you can set these configuration options at the HttpClient Level by defining a **RequestConfig**. Here is an example below:

```
 RequestConfig requestConfig = RequestConfig.custom()
                .setConnectionRequestTimeout(60 * 1000)
                .setConnectTimeout(60 * 1000)
                .setSocketTimeout(60 * 1000)
                .build();
```

Hope this helps.